# Microsoft Azure: How to run a Python program on a virtual machine (VM)?

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I need to run a Python program on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine (VM), because it uses a significant amount of memory (over 12 GB), so I need to run it in a virtual machine in the cloud, which would provide enough memory.

However, I didn't seem to find an option in the virtual machine's dashboard which lets me run a Python program on it?

Comment: You’ll need to install python on the VM (assuming it is not installed by default), copy your application to the VM and run it.

Comment: @GauravMantri Where on the Azure dashboard does it allow me to run a pip command to install Python?

Comment: It won't be on the dashboard.  You need to log into the box, and run a command like `pip install <package>`.  The machine, for these purposes, is like any other machine, you must manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can RDP or SSH into your Azure virtual machine, then you can install the application or execute the scripts as on the traditional VM as you would do.

You'll use the Connect button in the Azure portal to start a Remote Desktop (RDP) session from a Windows desktop. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon

Alternatively, you will create and use an SSH RSA public-private key file pair for SSH client connections. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed

Furthermore, you can use an Azure network security group to filter network traffic to and from Azure virtual machines in an Azure virtual network. Read [security rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#security-rules) and [how to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, for VMs you will not find any option to install software from Azure Portal. This is something you would need to do by connecting to your Virtual Machine.

You can connect to your VMs using multiple ways: Remote Desktop Connection, SSH, and Bastion etc. You will see all of these options in Azure Portal in the overview blade for your VM. Please see this link as an example of how to connect to your Windows VM using RDP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon.

Once you're connected to your VM, you can install software (python in your case). Installation mechanism would depend on the VM Operating System. Next you will need to copy your application code/binaries in the VM and run it there while still connected to your VM.